# Create a vector in R from the given values and the number of times they present

Tags: r

Hi i have two vectors one for values as val=c(2.2, 3.4, 5.6) and other for repetitions as times=c(4,1,2) number of times they present.

I want to create a vector as [2.2 2.2 2.2 2.2 3.4 5.6 5.6 ]

Comment: i got it  as c(rep(val,times))

Comment: @user3710546 I have not found this solution on help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> val <- c(2.2, 3.4, 5.6)
> times <- c(4,1,2) 
> rep(val, times)
[1] 2.2 2.2 2.2 2.2 3.4 5.6 5.6
```